# Como não carregar a pagina ao clicar no option do select?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho o seguinte select, toda vez que seleciono algum option ele recarrega a pagina, até ai tudo bem, porém eu quero fazer com que ao clicar no option nAtualiza, ele simplesmente não atualizaria a pagina, será que tem como? Obrigado!

```
    <select id="filtro" name="filtro" class="form-control" onchange="this.form.submit()">
       <option value="">Selecione</option>
       <option value="assunto"></option>
       <option value="nAtualiza"></option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Queres enviar dados para o servidor mas sem recarregar a página, é isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim:

```js
document.getElementById('filtro').addEventListener('change', function() {
  if(this.value != 'nAtualiza') {
    console.log('submit');
    this.form.submit();
  }
});
```

```html
<form> 
<select id="filtro" name="filtro" class="form-control">
   <option value="">Selecione</option>
   <option value="assunto">Assunto</option>
   <option value="nAtualiza">nAtualiza</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Tire o evento `onchange` do seu `select` e adicione esse javascript ao seu arquivo.

Comment: Obrigado!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Adicione uma condição para a execução da sua função.

```
<select id="filtro" name="filtro" class="form-control" onchange="this.value !== 'nAtualiza' && this.form.submit()">
   <option value="">Selecione</option>
   <option value="assunto"></option>
   <option value="nAtualiza"></option>
</select>
```

O trecho modificado no código acima corresponde à `this.value !== 'nAtualiza' && this.form.submit()`. É uma forma curta de dizer "execute `this.form.submit()` se `this.value` for diferente de `'nAtualiza'` .